# javaCV Maven project

Tags: maven, javacv

I downloaded the javaCV project from here

https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

then I tried to import it in Netbeans, but i got the following error

```
Failed to execute goal on project javacv: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.bytedeco:javacv:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:jar:3.0.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg:jar:2.6.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flycapture:jar:2.7.3.19-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libdc1394:jar:2.2.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:libfreenect:jar:0.5.2-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:videoinput:jar:0.200-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:artoolkitplus:jar:2.3.1-1.0-SNAPSHOT, 
org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:flandmark:jar:1.07-1.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not find artifact org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

I also tried to install it manually, but I got the same error. What shoud I do to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|bytedeco there does not exists a version of `1.0.-Snapshot`.

So you have to change the dependencies list to the old version:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
  </dependency>
```

and also for javacpp:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
    <artifactId>javacpp-presets</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>
```

etc.

I think the author forgot to publish the "new version".

Comment: I modified the pom.xml as you suggest, along with other modification to other dependecies to make them compliant with the Maven central. However now I have a bunch of compilation errors, for example `import static org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_videoio.*` gives me an error

Comment: It seems, org.bytedeco:javacpp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT is current only available as source code (see https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets ). I think you can ask the community from http://groups.google.com/group/javacpp-project how to create nessecary binaries.